# Groupings: orderless version?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Consider the following groupings code:

```
Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> 2, B -> 2}]
```

This generates:

```
 {A[2, 1], B[2, 1], A[A[1, 1], 1], A[1, A[1, 1]], A[B[1, 1], 1], 
  A[1, B[1, 1]], B[A[1, 1], 1], B[1, A[1, 1]], B[B[1, 1], 1], 
  B[1, B[1, 1]]}
```

In other words, the expressions with heads A and heads B over the arguments given by integer partition are generated.

These expressions correspond to expression trees of which Orderless versions can be obtained (``Orderless" in the sense of Mathematica, for trees, i.e. essentially trees identified up to permutations of children of a node).

Is there an Orderless version for Groupings?

I tried something like:

```
    Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> 2, B -> 2}, Orderless]
```

Or:

```
    Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> 2, B -> 2, Orderless}]
```

both of which produce errors.

I would like to obtain an efficient way to only keep ``Orderless versions of the expressions'' (as determined by the orderless versions of their expression trees).

Note that a distinction of heads matters, i.e. A and B are not interchangeable).

Comment: what  is the desired output for your example?

Comment: does `SetAttributes[{A,B}, Orderless]` work?

Comment: ... or `Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {foo -> 2, bar -> 2}, Sort]`?

Comment: Sort won't do it as it keeps copies of identical trees (generated by Sort). I found the answer though, copied below

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer:

```
Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> {2, Orderless}, B -> {2, Orderless}}]
```

this returns:

```
 {A[2, 1], B[2, 1], A[A[1, 1], 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[A[1, 1], 1], 
  B[B[1, 1], 1]}
```